# Run new/updated application files without restarting the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating an `http` project, and I am wondering what is the best way to non-server files? The main server won't change much so, instead of writing all the code in the `server.js` file, I would like to write it's application logic in other files. Instead of restarting the server every time we update those files, what can we do? I was thinking of doing an `interval` every 5 minutes or so to refresh the files, but is there a better way to do it?

Example (**server.js**):

```
var http = require('http');

// Load the initial app
require('./app/main.js');

// Reload the app every 5 minutes
setInterval(function(){
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./app/main.js')];
    require('./app/main.js');
}, 300000);

// Listen and handle requests
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);
server.listen(8000);
```

So, that is my thoughts of how to reload the app without restarting the server, but is there a better way?

Comment: Usually, you can't just replace running module files with new files.  There is typically state, module handles in use, etc...  I imagine a reload could be written, but you'd have to suspend activity by the server during the reload anyway since it would be in an partially initialized state until the reload was done.   I'd be very surprised if all this custom development was actually worth avoiding an occasional server restart.  It will really, really complicate development.

Comment: If you're trying to do super high availability, then the usual way to do that is with a load balancer and multiple server processes.  Take one server process out of the load balancer, update it, restart it, put it back in the load balancer, then do the same with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about restarting for development, you should look into nodemon. https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: I am looking for development and production if possible

Comment: production is a whole other story and depends on what kind of strategies you use for new releases. typically I don't see people using a restart for new code, rather they do a new deploy.

Comment: We currently don't use node, and we are learning so I am not sure what a "new deploy" really means with node. We currently use PHP which runs and works MUCH differently.

Comment: what i've seen and like personally is immutable servers. so if you change your code you spin up a new instance with your new code rather than just changing the code on your existing server. i'm not aware of how it's typically done with php projects.

Comment: with php we just put the page's code in the root directory and it instantly works. We have git so we just do a checkout of the new code, within a cron every 5 minutes and it just starts working on the servers

Comment: @TheBoogieMan - you will need to think differently for node.js than you do for PHP because node.js is a continuous running process.  Your PHP method does not really apply to node.js and it won't help you try to engineer something that works the same way.  You're likely going to need to restart your server process only when you've deployed new code which hopefully isn't very often (except during development).